# Как сделать кнопку с выпадающим списком команд в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Как сделать кнопку, после нажатия которые показывается весь список команд с описанием?

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно написать в Botfather в Телеграм.
Вводите команду /mybots , открывается список ваших ботов. Выбираете нужный. У вас открывается меню. Здесь нужно выбрать Edit Bot, а затем Edit Commands.

Ну или можно организовать следующим образом. Создать словарь с командами и описанием.

```
commands = {'/start': 'Нажмите для запуска бота', '/help': 'Нажмите для просмотра доступных команд'}
```

И уже из него вытягивать инфу в сообщение. Либо выводить на нового члена чата, либо на определённую команду.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_member'])
# или
@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def commands(message: types.Message)
    for command, discription in commands:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{command}\n{discription}')
```

Можно и клавиатуру сразу прикрутить в сообщение. Собрать из ключей словаря.

Answer (score 0):

@botfather -> /mybots -> Edit Commands

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]